# Can we call functions before defining it?

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    m();
}

void m()
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

**Output**

`hi`

**Warnings**

```
main.c:11:10: warning: conflicting types for 'm' [enabled by default]
     void m()
          ^
main.c:7:9: note: previous implicit declaration of 'm' was here
         m();
         ^
```

Why this program runs successfully even though `m()` is called before it is defined?
And what is the meaning of the warning?

Comment: What compiler are you useing ? Some of them (like Visual Studio) enables you to write code, that is  not C99 standard and succesfully runs

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C89 allow this by implicitly converting the return type of function and parameter passed to it to `int`.  See [here](http://ideone.com/IeUs6V).

But, this is not valid in C99 and later. This has been omitted from the standard. Either you have to declare a prototype for your function or define it before `main`. See the result [here](http://ideone.com/hdOgYq). There is a compile time error in this case.

Comment: This is running perfectly in CodeBlocks and online compilers

Comment: Why it is working? Even though I've defined m() after main()?

Comment: Compile your code in C99 mode. See the links in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't declare a function in K&RC/C89, it's implicitly declared as returning `int`. Since yours returns `void` there's a mismatch.

If you add a prototype:

```
void m(void);
```

...before it's called, it'll fix things.

Comment: I understand that, but why is the code running?
Shouldn't there be compile time error?

Comment: @PankajMahato: At least if memory serves, no. If you try to use the mismatched return type, you get undefined behavior, but since you're ignoring it, you probably even have defined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can declare it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// declare m()
void m();

void main()
{
    // use m()
    m();
}

// define m()
void m()
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that I can declare it. But how it is running without declaring?

Answer (score 3):

function declaration needs to be add before the first call of the function.
A full declaration includes the return type and the number and type of the arguments. This is also called the function prototype.

So you are  Missing function prototype.

Add function declaration as `void m();` to the code.

**Edit:**

C program allow to use [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)
.

> In your case `void m();` represents forward declaration of a function and is the function's prototype. After processing this declaration, the compiler would allow the user to refer to the entity `m` in the rest of the program.
>
> Definition for a function must be provided somewhere (same file or other, where it would be responsibility of the linker to correctly match references to particular function in one or several object files with its definition, which must be unique, in another): (*From wikipedia page*)

That is why defining function after main work in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - It is called using prototypes.

I.e. put

```
void m();
```

At the start of the file

Comment: You answered my second question. I want the first one too.

Comment: @Pankaj Mahato - The compiler tries an educated guess (i.e. `int m();`) is required just to see if that wworks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant normally.
The code would print the error something like this if the function is not defined before invoking it:

```
s.c: In function 'main':
s.c:4:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'm' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    4 | m();
      | ^
s.c: At top level:
s.c:8:6: warning: conflicting types for 'm'
    8 | void m(){
      |      ^
s.c:4:1: note: previous implicit declaration of 'm' was here
    4 | m();
      | ^
```

So, it is always a good practice to declare method before or inside of main method especially if you are defining a method outside the scope of main function.
The code snippet for best practice has been provided below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void m();

void main()

{

m();

}

void m()

{

printf("hi");

}
```