# When using fabs, fmin, fmax in a C program, why doesn't the compiler/linker report an error if math.h is not included?

Tags: c, visual-c++, math

When compiling a C program in Visual Studio 2013 the following may produce different results:

```
#include <math.h>

void bar(void) {
    double f = fabs(-1.0);
    /* f is 1.0 */
}
```

and

```
void foo(void) {
    double f = fabs(-1.0);
    /* f is 0 */
}
```

and the same snippet **without including math.h**. When omitting the include, the compiler does not report an error and assumes `fabs` has the following signature `int fabs()`.

Is there anyway to force the compiler to report this as an error or even a warning?

Answer (score 0):

In older C standards if a function is used before it's declared then it's assumed to receive an unknown number of arguments (under [default promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1255775/995714) like in variadic functions such as `printf`) and return `int`. The compiler will expect the symbol to be fixed later during linking stage so no errors should be reported

So without including `math.h` the compiler doesn't know the prototype of `fabs` and will assume that it accepts any kinds of parameters and returns `int`. Then when linking the linker really found a symbol with the expected name and resolves to that function, but due to the mismatch in the function signature [the behavior is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31196278/995714). Turn on all warnings and you'll see something about implicit return type

In VS2013 I got the below warning even without increasing the warning level

```
Warning 1   warning C4013: 'fabs' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

For more information read

- [Why can I call a function in C without declaring it but not in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35367208/995714)
- [Can we call functions before defining it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21487894/995714)
- [Implicit declaration in C language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44226234/995714)
- [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434763/995714)
- [Why the error of - calling the function before being declared, is not shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11881300/995714)
- [C language - calling functions without function prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22441345/995714)

Comment: I compiled the code with the maximum warning level in Visual Studio 2013, but couldn't find any relevant warning or error

Comment: it may depend on compiler. Using gcc in strict c99 mode emits `warning: implicit declaration of function 'fabs' [-Wimplicit-function
-declaration]` and `warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'fab
s' [enabled by default]` warning

Comment: @bennypk VS is a C++ compiler so you need to compile in C mode by using `.c` file extension, that'll give you the warning. In C++ that won't even compile because there's no implicit int return in C++

Comment: read more [warning: implicit declaration of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function) [C function calls: Understanding the “implicit int” rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220463/c-function-calls-understanding-the-implicit-int-rule) [What does “implicit declaration of function” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161304/what-does-implicit-declaration-of-function-mean)

Comment: Let me emphasize that the code is compiled as C with VS. When the same codebase is compiled with gcc, gcc gladly emits a warning. The question again, is how to make VS report a warning or error.

Comment: as I said, when compiling in VS as a `.c` file it automatically emits a warning

Comment: You need warning level `/W3` or higher. With `/W3` I see: ` warning C4013: 'fabs' undefined; assuming extern returning int`

Comment: @njuffa yes the default warning level is `/W3` so you don't need to change it unless you've lowered it before

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Complete agreement. I should have directed my comment directly at the asker, as I was responding to his most recent comment.

Comment: I checked again and the warning (now treated as an error) appears. Not sure why it didn't appear before. I must have somehow missed it. Thanks again

Comment: to some one who downvoted this: what's wrong in this answer, is it too hard to type a comment?