# Why is a function prototype not needed in C if there is no return in a function defined after main()?

Tags: c, gcc

As expected following code generates an error if prototype `double cubenum();` is not declared as required in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Answer is: %f", cubenum(3.0));
    return 0;
}

double cubenum(double number){
    double result = number * number * number;
    return result;
}
```

Whereas if cubenum definition is above is replaced with following definition without return then it does not generate any error when cubenum prototype is not declared:

```
void cubenum(double number){
    double result = number * number * number;
    printf("Answer is: %f", result);
}
```

And when prototype is declared as void cubenum(); with above cubenum definition without return it generates following error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in xxx(compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\xxx\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\xxx\main.c|10|error: invalid use of void expression|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Line 10 was when tested:     `printf("Answer is: %f", cubenum(3.0));`

So, question is:

Why a function which does not have a return, prototype declaration is not required and if declared gives error in the above example?

GCC version info

```
gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
```

Comment: Regarding the last error, how can you use the returned value of a function that doesn't return a value? (Like, what would `printf("Answer is: %f", cubenum(3.0))` print if `cubenum` doesn't return anything?)

Comment: I still get the warning: https://repl.it/repls/EverlastingOrangeMemoryallocator

Comment: @Ayxan It's related, but will not answer this question.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the [very first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367222/10147399) there seems to answer just this question "The reason this could compile is because in the very old days it was allowed by the c standard, namely the C89 standard.", meaning this is no longer valid C.

Comment: @Ayxan If I'm reading it right, it's not about forward declaration. OP asks why the last one does not produce the error as first one. OP expects the error, not the other way around.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Looks like I didn't quite understand the question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I added the [tag:c89] tag, because this no longer valid since [tag:c90]

Comment: @Ayxan It's misleading to tell anyone who would ask this question that this is "no longer valid C".  Implicit function declarations were removed from the C _standard_ in the 1999 revision, but they are still accepted by default by the most recent versions of all three of GCC, LLVM, and MSVC [as of late 2019]. Only when implicit declarations are rejected _in the default compilation mode_ by the major compilers will it be correct to say that they are "no longer valid C" -- but once that happens, we won't get variants on this question anymore.

Comment: What compiler options are you using? What gcc version are you using? Do you get any warnings from the compiler? What build system or how are you building the source? My gcc gives me different errors, so I guess I can't replicate the issue. But anyway [I can replicate that](https://godbolt.org/z/iN4oov) in one case `conflicting types for cubenum` is an error and in the other it's a warning. `|In function 'main':|
C:\xxx\main.c|10|` the error you posted does not correspond to the source code you posted - there is no `main` function on line 10, on line 10 there is `cubenum` definition.

Comment: @zwol Compiler extensions are just that - extensions to the language. The C language defined by ISO C99 and onward standards do not allow implicit function declarations. Therefore, it is not a part of the ISO C programming language anymore. It's also a universally accepted bad style... GCC does complain when you use implicit declarations even with no warning options for example.

Comment: @Ayxan Please read what I said again. Yes, it's technically an extension relative to C2011, but as long as it is an extension that is accepted _in the default compilation mode_ by _all three of the most commonly used C compilers_, everyone who isn't a language lawyer will naturally think that it _is_ part of the C language, and telling them that it isn't will only confuse them.  Pedantry is bad pedagogy.

Comment: @KamilCuk Updated GCC version. Also, added what was actually there in line 10. Line number got affected because of few extra blank lines in the executed code, also prototype declaration line added as mentioned in the question.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with what you're asking about, but when you use `printf` you almost always ought to have a `\n` at the very end of the format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have written your program in a way that is characteristic of *very old* C programs, dating to the 1980s or 1990s, before "prototyped" function declarations became preferred style.  C compilers, to this day, bend over backwards to keep those very old programs working, preserving language features that they rely on, but that were never standardized or have been removed from the C standard since 1989.

Perfectly correct modern style for your first program would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double cubenum(double);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Answer is: %f", cubenum(3.0));
    return 0;
}

double cubenum(double number)
{
    double result = number * number * number;
    return result;
}
```

with a *prototyped* forward declaration of `cubenum`, `double cubenum(double);`

It's important to understand that `double cubenum();` is NOT a prototyped declaration in C, but rather a declaration that says `cubenum` takes *any number and type* of arguments.  If you wanted to specify that `cubenum` takes *no* arguments, you would have to write  `double cubenum(void);` This is also why I changed `int main()` to `int main(void)`.

When you leave the forward declaration out entirely,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Answer is: %f", cubenum(3.0));
    return 0;
}

double cubenum(double number)
{
    double result = number * number * number;
    return result;
}
```

the C compiler sees a call to `cubenum` with no previous declaration for it at all.  This was common in those very old C programs I mentioned.  They relied on a feature called *implicit declaration* that was part of the original C standard but removed from its 1999 revision (commonly known as "C99").  Basically, the compiler assumes that the programmer meant to write `int cubenum();` above `main`, but lazily left it out.  This means `cubenum` takes *any number and type* of arguments (NOT that it takes no arguments) and returns `int`.  So, leaving `main` out of it for now, it's like you wrote

```
int cubenum();
double cubenum(double number) { ... }
```

and the compiler rejects the program because the definition of `cubenum` has a different return type from the (implicit) forward declaration.  That part I think you already understood.

Now, when you change `cubenum` to return nothing, so your complete program is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Answer is: %f", cubenum(3.0));
    return 0;
}

void cubenum(double number)
{
    double result = number * number * number;
    printf("Answer is: %f", result);
}
```

the implicit function declaration is still `int cubenum()` and the prototype from the function definition is `void cubenum(double)`.  As another compatibility feature for those very old C programs, these are considered *not* to be conflicting return types, and the compiler accepts the program.  This is because the type `void` was invented in the 1989 C standard.  Programs written before then would have instead given `cubenum` no return type at all...

```
cubenum(number)
    double number;
{
    double result = number * number * number;
    printf("Answer is: %f", result);
}
```

... which technically declares it to return `int`!  Immediately post-C89, those programs got updated to give their functions with no return value the type `void`, but it was too much work to stop relying on implicit declarations for them at the same time, so compilers grew a special case where `int foo()` and `void foo()` are considered not to be in conflict.

(Incidentally, because of yet another backward compatibility consideration — "old-style function definitions", which you can see in the above code fragment — preferred style in C is to put the opening curly brace of a function definition on its own line, even if all other opening braces are "cuddled".)

And finally, when you *do* put `void cubenum();` above `main`, only then is the compiler officially aware that `cubenum` returns nothing.  When it does know that, it knows that `printf("%f", cubenum(3.0));` is incorrect because it's using the nonexistent return value of `cubenum`, and it rejects the program for *that* reason.

---

You shouldn't be relying on any of these backward compatibility features in a new program.  I see that you are using GCC, so set your compilation options to something like this:

```
-std=gnu11 -g -Og -Wall -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror
```

which will disable almost all of the backward compatibility features.  (There are a whole lot more [warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and you may want to consider turning on more of them.  `-Wwrite-strings` and `-Wextra` are particularly useful for new code IMNSHO.)  (Do NOT use the hyper-conformant mode, `-std=c11`, until you know considerably more about what you are doing; it can break the system headers, and it enables the "trigraph" misfeature that you almost certainly don't want.)

Answer (score 1):

> Whereas if cubenum definition is above is replaced with following
>   definition without return then it does not generate any error when
>   cubenum prototype is not declared:

Because when you don't have explicit declaration for a function, some C compilers will do it implicitly. Normally, it gives `int` for both return type and arguments.

A good-enough compiler should inform you about implicit declaration.

It's dangerous, because compiler won't know the exact prototype of the function.So you may have a very unpredictable result.

> And when prototype is declared as void cubenum(); with above cubenum
>   definition without return it generates following error:

This is another problem, since you try to `printf` the return value of a `void` function.