# printf("\n") \n has randomly stopped working anywhere in my code VS2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, printf

```
//testing some structs
#include <stdio.h>

struct books {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    char subject[100];
    int book_id;
} book;

//Function Declairations
int print_book(struct books book);

int main() {
    struct books book1;
    struct books book2;

    strcpy(book1.title, "Spot goes to the beach");
    strcpy(book1.author, "Mr Biggles");
    strcpy(book1.subject, "A story of a stupid little dog that goes to the beach and chases birds.");
    book1.book_id = 684687654;

    strcpy(book2.title, "The Cat in the Hat");
    strcpy(book2.author, "Dr Seuse");
    strcpy(book2.subject, "A mischeviouse cat come to visit and causes such a mess");
    book2.book_id = 5754454;

    printf("Available books for hire from the library\n");

    print_book(book1);
    print_book(book2);
}

int print_book(struct books book) {
    //prints the details of a books struct parsed as a parameter
    printf("\nBook Title: %s", book.title);
    printf("\nBook Author: %s", book.author);
    printf("\nBook Subject: %s", book.subject);
    printf("\nBook ID: %d", book.book_id);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Hey guys for some reason `\n` has randomly stopped working. I decided to add another `\n` at the bottom just to separate the output from the "press any key to continue..." from the console window at the end but it's not working now.

I've even tried going to line 28 and just inserting more `\n`'s eg...

```
printf("Available b\n\n\n\n\n\n\nooks for hire from the library\n");
```

with no difference in the output.

Comment: did you recompile it..

Comment: `int print_book()` doesn't return *anything* let alone an `int`.

Comment: yeah cheers forgot to do a return statement. But that isnt the problem. Was all working fine then just wasnt all of sudden. I just tried copying all the code into a new file and now I get strcpy() is undefined. I think VS is broken

Comment: okay something weird is definitely going on.. Tried heaps of things and restarted VS still weird behavour.    Then I restarted windows and opened the original file that was having trouble. With no changes all the \n's work properly now.    Could my recent upgrade to Windows 10 broken Visual Studio?

Comment: maybe vs was not doing a clean rebuild..

Comment: 1) check the warnings when compiling: you're missing some headers (like string.h/cstring for `strcpy`) 2) `int main()` should be `int main ( void )`, and is not returning an int 3) though not an answer, try to see if using `puts` makes any difference, instead of `printf("\n");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `int print_book(struct books book);` → `void print_books(...)`.

   You didn't return anything from that function
2. You didn't include `string.h` so the compiler **doesn't know the declaration of `strcpy()`** and assumes that it *returns `int`* and take *any number of arguments* via default promotion. So your code invokes undefined behavior. It may run this time but not some other time or on other systems. See

   - [Can we call functions before defining it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21487894/995714)
   - [Default argument promotions in C function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1255775/995714)
   - [Function declaration order matters in c language or am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13297233/995714)
   - [Are prototypes required for all functions in C89, C90 or C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434763/995714)

Comment: Bit weird how it let me use strcpy if I need string.h included then complained later on after running it 50 times. VS is so weird. Thanx for all the help guys.

Comment: It's not weird. C allows a function to be used without or before it's declaration, with implied return and argument types. You should always enable all warnings to here what the compiler shout at you.